# Flow layout in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to create a rich text template with Jasper. The result should be a document with many paragraphs, indented lists, some have sublists, and titles. The whole document will spread on several pages and since many parts of the document are generated from data the page breaks are not fixed.

My first question is, is my use case actually something one should do with jasper or should I rather set up something with markdown or even LateX? *All templates and examples I was able to find where more one pagers with tables and graphs but no several pages documents, however Jasper has a fast creation time and would also be able to create word files (in addition to pdfs) which is a big plus.*

If I am using Jasper for the right purpose then should I use a new text field for each paragraph or should I write the whole document in one text field? *I don't like the idea of writing everything into one since Jasper doesn't allow to format the code all to well and also I had problems with new pages.*

Or should I create a new text field for each paragraph? *this is what I tried below but I struggle with the layout, the paragraphs come over each other and some parts are repeated on every page while some never appear. My whole document is messed up and I can not understand why, changing parameters does make changes but I can not comprehend what is happening*

So if I should create a new text field for each paragraph how do I set the layout so that they appear after each other. They will be generated hence the length is not fixed and I want the paragraphs to be evenly spread not have different spaces between them.

To show the problems I have, see following `jrxml` file which compiles to a document with a messed up layout. *I know that I could just set all text fields to float and set them to the exact position but that is not the idea since I will have generated fields, so what I look for is some kind of flowlayout.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="daade75b-7134-4af7-b206-2451426de5a9">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="72" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="36" uuid="a253abbc-8696-4ab4-8d58-bc33a059982c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Hello"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="36" width="555" height="36" uuid="5494bb7d-0f10-479c-aad7-61ba1a10868c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Consulting agreement]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="19" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="367" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="55" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="892c2a2f-d320-4dc2-b31a-c15bccb6af43"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                    <paragraph firstLineIndent="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tincidunt rhoncus vestibulum. In vitae neque lectus. Donec nec elementum sem. Donec ullamcorper leo in felis mattis, sit amet fringilla sapien semper. In consectetur neque porttitor semper vulputate. Nunc et tellus purus. Nam et urna nec urna fringilla molestie. Duis eleifend rutrum porttitor."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="55" width="555" height="52" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ba36dcb6-d88f-43ea-bfc1-16dfcb1d5837"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                    <paragraph firstLineIndent="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Phasellus euismod, sapien commodo iaculis lacinia, urna odio pretium quam, in scelerisque dolor nisi at purus. Proin at condimentum lectus. Phasellus vitae felis augue. Praesent vulputate ipsum nibh, in cursus metus vehicula quis. Vestibulum facilisis elit tristique, posuere sem vitae, rutrum dui. Sed varius eros nec euismod bibendum. Sed dapibus condimentum lectus, semper dignissim felis rhoncus sit amet. In viverra varius tincidunt. Aenean eu tincidunt nulla, eu sagittis ante. Duis ullamcorper eros ut tincidunt mattis. Quisque ac dolor imperdiet, volutpat lorem ut, luctus turpis."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="107" width="555" height="52" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="71df41c1-9607-40b7-8dd8-897882470e88"/>
                <textElement markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" firstLineIndent="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Donec eget ligula vitae tellus tincidunt ornare at nec lacus. Aliquam interdum lobortis hendrerit. Suspendisse tempus ipsum urna, vel convallis est luctus et. Duis fermentum ipsum mi, sed lobortis arcu fermentum in. Mauris sagittis nisl arcu, at fermentum justo tincidunt quis. Curabitur tristique nunc et nulla ornare, eget bibendum nisl efficitur. Quisque porta sem sed quam porttitor tristique eget in ex. Maecenas scelerisque felis eu est vulputate condimentum. Donec efficitur lobortis tristique. Praesent nulla augue, mollis non elementum sit amet, luctus in arcu. Etiam viverra orci sit amet ante mattis aliquet."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="159" width="555" height="52" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="71df41c1-9607-40b7-8dd8-897882470e88"/>
                <textElement markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" firstLineIndent="0" leftIndent="30"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pretium malesuada dapibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur suscipit metus vitae tellus laoreet semper. Fusce vehicula a libero sed venenatis. Vestibulum accumsan egestas nisl. Sed at enim vel mauris ornare auctor vel vitae nisl. Morbi sed lobortis arcu. Duis blandit aliquam auctor."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="211" width="555" height="52" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="7ab5d201-6c88-4932-bc84-941900d1dc39"/>
                <textElement markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" firstLineIndent="0" leftIndent="40"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Phasellus a nulla ornare, dapibus nunc in, scelerisque urna. Integer vestibulum neque at tellus cursus congue. Aliquam tempor mauris porta, egestas ante vitae, sollicitudin enim. Vivamus cursus convallis mauris non varius. Integer euismod eros cursus justo pharetra, nec fringilla ante tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In facilisis at augue ac tempor."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="263" width="555" height="52" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="3b3879c4-fd99-4e49-b8b2-7f15f09d1667"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                    <paragraph firstLineIndent="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Norse mythology is the body of myths of the North Germanic people stemming from Norse paganism and continuing after the Christianization of Scandinavia and into the Scandinavian folklore of the modern period. The northernmost extension of Germanic mythology, Norse mythology consists of tales of various deities, beings, and heroes derived from numerous sources from both before and after the pagan period, including medieval manuscripts, archaeological representations, and folk tradition."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="315" width="555" height="52" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="c922c7c9-93d3-4cc3-b4df-8ab7f6f80090"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                    <paragraph firstLineIndent="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Most of the surviving mythology centres on the plights of the gods and their interaction with various other beings, such as humanity and the jötnar, beings who may be friends, lovers, foes or family members of the gods. The cosmos in Norse mythology consists of Nine Worlds that flank a central cosmological tree, Yggdrasil. Units of time and elements of the cosmology are personified as deities or beings. Various forms of a creation myth are recounted, where the world is created from the flesh of the primordial being Ymir, and the first two humans are Ask and Embla. These worlds are foretold to be reborn after the events of Ragnarök when an immense battle occurs between the gods and their enemies, and the world is enveloped in flames, only to be reborn anew. There the surviving gods will meet, and the land will be fertile and green, and two humans will repopulate the world."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="367" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="315" width="555" height="52" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="4e12811e-3a76-4e19-86d1-08e2a1239c23"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                    <paragraph firstLineIndent="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Numerous gods are mentioned in the source texts such as the hammer-wielding, humanity-protecting thunder-god Thor, who relentlessly fights his foes; the one-eyed, raven-flanked god Odin, who craftily pursues knowledge throughout the worlds and bestowed among humanity the runic alphabet; the beautiful, seiðr-working, feathered cloak-clad goddess Freyja who rides to battle to choose among the slain; the vengeful, skiing goddess Skaði, who prefers the wolf howls of the winter mountains to the seashore; the powerful god Njörðr, who may calm both sea and fire and grant wealth and land; the god Freyr, whose weather and farming associations bring peace and pleasure to humanity; the goddess Iðunn, who keeps apples that grant eternal youthfulness; the mysterious god Heimdallr, who is born of nine mothers, can hear grass grow, has gold teeth, and possesses a resounding horn; the jötunn Loki, who brings tragedy to the gods by engineering the death of the goddess Frigg's beautiful son Baldr; and numerous other deities."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Consider https://freemarker.apache.org/ with https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer to generate PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use [Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) which is more suitable for your use case instead of JasperReports which are used more for generation of reports, statistics and other table and grid structured documents.

For example we used Apache FOP for generation of contract documents with lot of paragraphs, addresses, personal data, page numbers, logos, etc.

Apache FOP uses [XSL-FO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) as a template and XML as a data source. It means that you create XSL-FO template (manually or using any FO editor), then you create or programmatically generate structured XML containing all paragraphs, lists, titles and other dynamic content and execute XSL transformation using Apache FOP where you can define various output formats like PDF, PS, RTF, PNG, ...

Internet is full of XSL-FO tutorials, you can look for example on [this one](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-xsl-fo/index.cfm).

**Update:** I forgot to mention [DocBook](https://docbook.org/) which defines semantic language for writing books, manuals, Bachelor thesis etc. Content is again stored in XML with structure defined by DocBook schema and then you can convert it into PDF using one of predefined templates. Conversion to PDF also uses Apache FOP but here you create only XML with content (XSL template is already done).